# How to make Python Command Prompt Unclickable?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, command, command-prompt

I am using Python 3.7 in Windows 10 as Development Environment. I wrote a continuous time application and I run my python script on command Prompt as:

```
cmd: runpythonscript.py
```

However if you put your mouse on the command prompt and click it, the command prompt pauses the code. I don't want any outside interrupt from command prompt unless it is closed.

Is there a way to do this?

Here a simple real time code that can be tried:

```
import time

def main():
    is_running = True
    time_slept = 0
    while is_running:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("I slept " + str(time_slept) +" seconds")
        time_slept += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: are you sure it actually pauses the code? i think you will find it just stops any printing to screen, and when you deselect the text you selected (so just another click) it will print all the text in one go

Comment: I believe it stops the code, you can try the code above, try pause it, wait a while, and press "Enter", it will continue to go where it left

Comment: I think this is a good question though :/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually default behaviour on most terminals on Linux. If you enter copy mode, the process is paused. You may remove the `quick edit mode` to achieve your desired behavior:
[image]
[image]

Sorry for the german labels, windows is really sick if you want to change the language. The stuff should be on the same place.